# How do i replace a dash character with a newline in a string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace all the dashes in the text with newlines, but it's not working. why not?

```
f = open('phrases.txt').readlines()
f = [f.strip('\n').lower() for f in f]
f = f.replace('- ','\n')
g = open('text.txt').read()
for phrase in f:
    if phrase in g:
        print(phrase)
```

Comment: Please provide more details about what you tried, the error you got, and what result you expected. That said, `replace()` doesn't work on `list`s.

Answer (score 0):

replace should be applied to strings, not list. Also using one variable name (i.e. `f`) for everthing is not a good practice:

```
f = open('conditions.txt').readlines()
f = [a_line.strip('\n').lower().replace('-', '\n') for a_line in f]
```

Comment: OP probably wants `[line for physical_line in lines for line in physical_line.rstrip('\n').lower().split('-')]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('conditions.txt','r')
lines = file.readlines()
text = "".join(lines)
finaltext = text.replace("-","\n")
```

Comment: Please provide more details on why this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now, but rather than syntax the problem was with the specific character I was encountering.

Make sure the character you are encountering is a dash `-` and not the unicode em dash `—` or even the unicode long dash `▬`

rather than using `string.replace('-', '')` I had to use `string.replace(u'\u2014', '')`

To check, print the `.encode()` of the character. A true dash will show `b'-'`